# how to create a table with json data type column

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

phpMyAdmin - ver 4.8.0.1 (latest).

I'm trying to create a table with `json` column.

```
CREATE TABLE `book` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `tags` json DEFAULT NULL,  // line 4
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Result - `error in your SQL syntax... on line 4`

When I go to `Structure` tab of an existing table and trying to change column type - there is no such option in the list.

It seems that phpMyAdmin does not support this type of data.

What is the solution, pls?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? This datatype was added in 5.7.

Comment: phpMyAdmin isn't the database, it's just a web interface. The version of MySQL is what's important, not the version of PMA.

Comment: PMA has supported the JSON data type since 4.6.0, but it probably checks the database version and hides it if the DB is older.

Comment: @Barmar, on the right info sidebar I see - 5.0.12. But I suppose I cannot upgrade mysql.

Comment: Wow, that's a really old version of MySQL. Talk to your database administrator.

Comment: @Barmar, problem is on my localhost, not on remote server. I'm using `xampp` on windows.

Comment: Then why can't you upgrade mysql?

Comment: @Barmar, how can I do that, pls?

Comment: GO to https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ and download the installer for the version you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you may upgrade from older to newer version - That's what I did on localhost several months ago.

As for me, MySQL Workbench did the trick smoothly and error free, please referrer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-database-mysql.html

And if you experience any problem during migration, ask here and we may help you along the process.